# Textarea resizes and triggers best_in_place blur event

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using the [best_in_place gem](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) on several textareas and sometimes (seemingly randomly) the textarea 'jumps' and triggers the blur event when I click save, prompting the "discard your changes" warning.

Here's the code:

```html
<p>
  Administrator Notes (<%= link_to 'Edit', '#', id: 'edit_notes_link', onclick:
  'event.preventDefault()' %>)
</p>
<div class="panel radius">
  <%= best_in_place [:admin, @booking], :notes, type: :textarea, ok_button:
  'Save', cancel_button: 'Cancel', activator: '#edit_notes_link', display_with:
  :simple_format, nil: '<i>None</i>' %>
</div>
```

And here's a GIF of the behaviour:

[image]

(And [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGJLLiv1DUU) that GIF was taken from)

I'm guessing that there's some JavaScript skulduggery going on somewhere but I don't know where to begin debugging it. If you've seen Best in Place behave like this or you have some pointers for how to debug it then I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: have you found a workaround for this?

Comment: @rmagnum2002 No, I never did figure it out and I'm no longer working on that project :/

Comment: What happens if you put :use_confirm => false into the options to turn off the Alert - does that change the behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using firebug try turning on log events to get more information. Here is an article explaining it http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-log-dom-events/

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue, and just removed the `ok_button`. It seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used best-in-place gem but
 I had a similar requirement. I've used [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)

Worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend breaking down the DOM breakpoint actions and checking the logs first if you are using the basic chrome dev tools , if you have to absolutely use best-in-place. Will help you isolate the issue.

But if not, [X-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) is a bit more easier to use.